# How to check Instant File Initialization is enabled or not in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I want to check Instant File Initialization is enabled or not in Azure SQL Server.

I have tried like this:

```
exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Database Instant File Initialization'
```

but I got an error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'xp_readerrorlog'.

I also tried with the dynamic management view `sys.dm_server_registry`, but this also throws an error:

> Invalid object name 'sys.dm_server_registry'.

So help me out...

Comment: might prefixing master. will work for you... `exec master.xp_readerrorlog  ....`

Comment: @ShakeerMirza still it is showing invalid object ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database Instant File Initialization is not available on Azure SQL Database as is shown in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

SQL Server instances running on an Azure VM can make use of the ability to clear a range of bytes in a page blob, provided by the [Put Page API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-page), to make instant log initialization a reality. For more information, please visit [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/09/11/instant-log-initialization-for-sql-server-in-azure/) blog.